# Ag-grid hide filter column

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I have custom filter in Ag-grid. Implemented according with this site:
[https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/)

And when I click filter and enter some values and click ApplyFilter, the icon's filter is displayed in the header:
[image: filter icon]

But when I click Clear filter, this icon doesn't disappeare.
How to hide this icon?

Comment: what exactly is your "Clear Filter" button doing? Please post the function it is calling, and if possible, the entire custom filter.

Comment: "Clear Filter" remove value from input and call method from `ag-grid` : `params.filterChangedCallback();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#filter-component), Please use `isFilterActive` function also

```
 isFilterActive(): boolean {
    return this.text != null && this.text !== '';
  }
```

and filter `onChange` method please call this method `filterChangedCallback` also

```
onChange(newValue): void {
    if (this.text !== newValue) {
      this.text = newValue;
      this.params.filterChangedCallback();
    }
  }
```

Here is working [Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#example-filter-component) Please go through it for more info.